# Cursor implement on PreparedStatement in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android-asynctask, cursor, prepared-statement, implements

So I am trying to implement a Cursor to my class so i can populate my datagrid (not sure if that is the right way to do it when i need to use callable for SP and prepared statement) which i made from this [guide here](http://codegineer.blogspot.dk/2011/11/datatable-for-datagrid.html) but i gets a

> DataGridActivity.Itemnumber is not abstract and does not override abstract method respond(Bundle) in Cursor

i am not sure how to implement the abstract method here as i
normaly use getstring methode for my prepared statements wonder if there is somehow i could do that instead to populate my grid instead of using the Cursor

```
public class Itemnumber extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> implements Cursor {
    String z = "";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                String sqli = "select ID,ItemNumber,Trashed,Sold from [file].[Item] where [ItemNumber] =?";
                preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqli);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, "test");
                ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                } else {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            z = "Exceptions";
        }
        return z;
    }
    @Override
    public Bundle respond(Bundle extras){
        moveToFirst();
        return Bundle.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

---

My Datagrid activity class

```
Cursor csr = new Itemnumber();
//create DataTable object
DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();
//define column
dtDataSource.addAllColumns(new String[]{"column_1", "column_2","column_3", "column_4});
//create DataRow
DataTable.DataRow drRow;

//populate data from cursor into DataSource
if(csr.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        drRow = dtDataSource.newRow();
        drRow.set("column_1", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("field_1")));
        drRow.set("column_2", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("field_2")));
        drRow.set("column_2", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("field_3")));
        drRow.set("column_4", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("field_4")));

        dtDataSource.add(drRow);
    } while(csr.moveToNext());
    csr.close();
}        
/**
 *  Prepare the DataGrid
 */
//initialize DataGrid
DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)findViewById(R.id.datagrid);
//define column style, bond each DataGrid column by DataTable column
dg.addColumnStyles(new DataGrid.ColumnStyle[]{
        new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.ID), "column_1", 80),
        new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.ItemNumber), "column_2", 120),
        new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.Trashed), "column_3", 100),
        new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.Sold), "column_4", 150)    
});
//set the DataTable as source
dg.setDataSource(dtDataSource);
//generate the DataGrid
dg.refresh();
```

Comment: yes thats the import android.database.Cursor;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with just use my prepaered statement.

As implementing all the abstract methodes and interfaces didn't seemed to be anything near logical

```
public class DataGridActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    //define column
    DataTable.DataRow drRow;
    DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();
    Button btnsearch;
    DataGrid dg;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.datagridt);
        dg = (DataGrid)findViewById(R.id.datagrid);
        btnsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass(this.getApplicationContext());


        /**
         *  Prepare the DataGrid
         */
        //initialize DataGrid
        //define column style, bond each DataGrid column by DataTable column
                dg.addColumnStyles(new DataGrid.ColumnStyle[]{
                new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.dito_nr), "column_1", 80),
                new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.Biltype), "column_2", 120),
                new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.kort_nr), "column_3", 100),
                new DataGrid.ColumnStyle(getString(R.string.Del_Type), "column_4", 150)

        });

    }


    public class Itemnumber extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        String z = "";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dtDataSource.addAllColumns(new String[]{"column_1", "column_2","column_3", "column_4"});
            drRow = dtDataSource.newRow();
            dtDataSource.add(drRow);
            dg.setDataSource(dtDataSource);
            dg.refresh();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
                    String sqli = "select ID,ItemNumber,Trashed,Sold from [file].[Item]";
                    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqli);
                    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        //create DataRow
                        drRow.set("column_1", rs.getString(1));
                        drRow.set("column_2", rs.getString(2));
                        drRow.set("column_3", rs.getString(3));
                        drRow.set("column_4", rs.getString(4));

                    } else {
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                z = "Exceptions";
            }
            return z;

        }
    }

    public void btnsearch (View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Itemnumber item = new Itemnumber();
        item.execute("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override last method in `Itemnumber` class. 
This method is in `interface Cursor`, and named: `respond(Bundle)`

So, if Your class `Itemnumber` implemented `Cursor`, please add

```
@Override
Bundle respond(Bundle extras){
   return Bundle.EMPTY; 
}
```

and implemented, what Your method must return

Comment: not sure if i had done it right as i still gets implement abstract metode movertofirst() in cursor

Comment: Ok, so I think, you can extend different abstract class, who implement all necessary methods from Cursor interface, otherwise you have next problem, so you must implements next method, and again and again. But now, you extend AsyncTask, so the problem can be in design

Comment: that doesn't seems to be logical to do it that way then there might be some other way around it probaly by using the datasource in the prepared statement instead

Comment: Ok, now read your problem again. So, did you implement this method moveToFirst() (boolean) in your `Itemnumber ` class? If, yes, what is a result?